# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void package name with method

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Not able to call any native method from java file.Getting this error not able to resolve.I already check method name in c file absolute match and .so file also loaded.Getting Log for JNI_OnLoad ENTRY.

Comment: Check you are using JNIEXPORT keyword on your C function. Also, post more code, then people can help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it is hard to judge.

I suggest to start with something super simple. For example, take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

This is super simple, Hello World, sample for JNI based codes.

Just take a look at all the pieces required to successfully run the code and try to replicate it in your environment.